# Have I implemented zxcvbn correctly as it is letting me type easy passwords

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been trying to get zxcvbn.js to work correctly (this is a jQuery library to test password strength), but I am not entirely sure if it is working properly. So I will explain.

After downloading zxcvbn you get a pile of folders eg dist,demo,data and the like and this is what I did.

I took the zxcvbn.js out of dist and included that in my code.
and I run a little jQuery to get it working(which I have included below).

This library gives you a score 0 to 4 and 4 being the best password, but I am getting 4 on passwords I don't consider that complicated, which is worrying
eg
asfsdffadssd,
aaasssssddddff,
fffddssffffffffss

You would think that the library would force you to use upper and lower case, and symbols in the password, but the above examples are giving me 4.

So now I am wondering if I have done this right because there are other things in the other folders I did not include. For instance there is a folder called data which male and female names and the such like.

My question is have I implemented it correctly, and if not, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my jQuery although I don't think that will help with the answer.
Ignore the progress bar stuff, as I haven't shown you my html.

```
$("#pass").on('change keyup', function() {

var result=zxcvbn($(this).val());

var response;
var progress;

   switch (result.score) {
  case 0:
    response = "Very Weak";
    progress=0;
    break;
  case 1:
    response = "Very Weak";
    progress=5;
    break;
  case 2:
    response = "Weak";
    progress=25;
    break;
  case 3:
    response = "Medium";
    progress=50;
    break;
  case 4:
    response = "Strong";
    progress=100;
    break;
    }
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({value: progress});
$('#status').text(response);
$('#result').val(response);

});
```

Comment: Check the passwords on their [test site](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209/zxcvbn/test/index.html): All your "unsafe" passwords require (regarding the algorithms used by zxcvbn) at least 10^11 guesses in the worst case. The site also explains the result. The classification `strong` (score = `4`) requires a [value of `>= 10^10`](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn#usage)

Comment: Hi Andreas, I tried one of the simple passwords on that site from above, and it seems that this simple password is not so simple. Is that strange?password:  aaasssssddddff
guesses_log10:  12.00008
score:  4 / 4
function runtime (ms):  35
guess times:
100 / hour:  centuries  (throttled online attack)
10  / second:  centuries  (unthrottled online attack)
10k / second:  3 years  (offline attack, slow hash, many cores)
10B / second:  2 minutes  (offline attack, fast hash, many cores)

Comment: The answer to your original question: Yes. You've implemented it correctly. If you think the result is "rubbish" because the underlying rules ([explained here](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/)) allow "simple" passwords then you shouldn't be using this library :)

Comment: After reading that page it seems sometimes a simple looking password is sometimes stronger than a pass like qwER43@! with symbols and capital letters. So I am happy that this has been answered. If you actually post your comment as an answer I can upvote you. Thanks